# If certain thing is included in input use anything after it

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hello I am currently working on a script that goes onto a website and automatically adds an Item to cart and purchases it for you I have a script that works except the only problem is that It is only able to checkout a single Item Item. Here is an example fo the script:

```
Item_code = input('Item code: ')
Size = input('Size: ')

def BOT():


   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable path=


   URL = .....

   driver.get(URL)

   while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector(Item_code).click()
            break

        except NoSuchElementException:
            driver.refresh()

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('s'))
select.select_by_visible_text(Size)
```

The script finds the item with the item code that I use and then selects the size from the users choice

I want to be able to write the code and the size but If I want to bot to cart two Items in different sizes I want it to type in a , and insert the next Item code and Size For example:

12345, 6789
Large, Medium

I want to somehow write that if a comma is included to read and use the code after it after it uses the first one and repeat that for every comma so If I wanted to get 3 or even 4 all I would have to do is this:

1234, 5678, 7890, etc...

Large, medium, Small, etc...

If anyone could Help me out I would really appreciate it I was thinking of something like

```
for , in BOT():
   (something like this but Im not sure )
```

I know how to tell the script that if Item_code == (',')  then do this but that would not work because it needs to be just the comma and I do not know how to tell it to repeat the BOT() a second time and use the second code and size

If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it thanks.

(I want to be able to share this bot since I have already made a GUI for it and all that)

(not sure if the executable path will work when sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem I created several custom functions and called them on special if statements

ex.

```
if Item.count(',') == (1):
    Cart1()
    Checkout()
```

etc.....